# css question - control starts floating when the browser is minimized

Tags: css

I have the following class.

```
.ZipCodeBox
{
  background: url('images/ZipCodeTextBox1.png') no-repeat top;
  width: 157px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 400px;
  left: 510px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

This is positioned fine when i have the browser full screen. But when i minimize the browser, the control starts shifting. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: position:absolute depends on which node up the HTML tree has position:relative set. Without this information a solution cannot be determined.

Comment: The problem is almost guaranteed to be something other than what you posted. A live example showing the behavior is the only way you're going to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provided enough information for us to give you right answer. But in my experience your problem is related to positioning. As Diodeus said `position:absolute` depends on which node up the HTML tree has `position:relative` set. Without this information a solution cannot be determined.
To learn more about positioning check out [this tutorial](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/) at A List Apart.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus and Mohsen. Setting the position to relative and altering the top and left property did solve the issue. Sorry for not providing the complete details. I am just testing this on my browser, so i couldn't provide the live url. Thanks all for your help.